# Migrations from scratch breaking as column in model doesn't exist yet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have following models and association.

```
class Stock < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stock_components, -> {order(:position)} 

  ...
  before_save :set_default_values

   def set_default_values
     self.material_cost = 0.0 if self.material_cost.nil?
   end
  ... 
end
```

When I run migrations from scratch, a migration that inserts a record in this table, breaks at line `self.material_cost = 0.0 if self.material_cost.nil?` with following  -

```
Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'stock_components.position' in 'order clause': SELECT `stocks`.* FROM `stocks` INNER JOIN `stock_components` ON `stocks`
.`id` = `stock_components`.`component_id` WHERE `stock_components`.`stock_id` = 1 ORDER BY `stock_components`.`position` ASC
```

This is because migration for adding position hasn't run yet.

What could be solution for this?

Comment: Why do you need migrations from scratch? You always can use `rake db:schema:load`. The only solution here is to comment out the line with `has_many` and return it back after migration

Comment: Does `stock_components` have `position ` column?

Comment: @gabbar Yes but the migration that adds `position` column runs after the failing migration causing this issue.

Comment: @Vasilisa This is part of our legacy product and for every new client installation we need to run migrations as they also contain data insertions

Answer (score 2):

That's really unfortunate, but it's a common issue which is almost never addressed.

When a data migration on a model is written, either to change or set values, or to add data, typically one relies on the application model (with all the corresponding callbacks etc).

But then at a later time, more callbacks are added, and previous migrations are broken. Even worse, a later migration might rename or remove a column, and the inserted data is not valid anymore.

The solution is that you should NEVER use application models in a migration, but rather some local model that uses whatever is in the database at the time:

```
class PopulateStock < ActiveRecord::Migration
  class Stock < ActiveRecord::Model
    self.table_name = 'stocks'
  end

  def up
    Stock.create(...)
  end
end
```

Now the `Stock` model that is referenced in the migration is completely defined by the status of the table at the time of migration (no extra columns, no callbacks etc) instead of depending on *all* the application model.

Unfortunately this means that you have to go through all your app's migrations and create local models for them until migrations can be run.

Comment: This is nice way of doing it but unfortunately doesn't work for me as there are lot of associations and methods that are used in migrations.

Comment: You need to add to each migration the minimum amount of code, the associations you need to make the migrations work assuming the tables are exactly at the pre-migrated state. What you cannot do is to have all your future associations, without a backing table, to a model used in a “past” migration.